# Is it possible to access the correct URL.resourceValues for an iCloud file that isn't downloaded?

Tags: swift, macos, appdelegate, nsurl

#### Problem

When grabbing the `.fileSizeKey` and `.localizedTypeDescriptionKey` on a `URL.resourceValues`'s for an non-downloaded iCloud file with the `.icloud` extension, I get an incorrect file size and the description is listed as Alias.

```swift
var url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/.image.png.icloud")
var fileResources: URLResourceValues?

let keys: Set<URLResourceKey> = [.localizedTypeDescriptionKey, .fileSizeKey]

do {
    guard let resources = try url?.resourceValues(forKeys: keys) else { return }
    fileResources = resources
} catch {}

print(fileResources?.localizedTypeDescription) // Alias
print(fileResources?.fileSize) // 192 bytes (when it should be 4MB)
```

#### What I've Tried

1. I've tried setting up a `NSFileCoordinator()` to request the metadata for the file but that didn't work.

```swift
var error: NSError?
let coordinator = NSFileCoordinator(filePresenter: nil)
coordinator.coordinate(readingItemAt: url!, options: .immediatelyAvailableMetadataOnly, error: &error) { URL in
    do {
        let resources = try URL.promisedItemResourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSizeKey])
        print(resources.fileSize) // 192 bytes (file type reads as Alias too)
    } catch {}
}
```

2. I've also tried MDItem and it does work, but it's unreliable because sometimes there's no metadata (on mail files for example) and I had to turn off sandboxing to get it to work.

```swift
let md = MDItemCreateWithURL(kCFAllocatorDefault, url! as CFURL) // nil if sandbox is enabled
let meta = MDItemCopyAttribute(md, kMDItemFSSize)
print(meta) // 4MB (correct size)
```

3. I've also tried taking the `.image.png.icloud` url and tried to find the alias original url, but it doesn't seem possible as the file isn't actually an alias.

#### What I'm Considering

I imagine this is possible somehow as Finder's Get Info Pane has no problem getting the info. I've wondered if maybe it's possible to change the file and remove the `'.'` and the `'.icloud'` components of the url temporarily but I'm not sure how to go about this because I believe it involves duplication or copying of the file.

**Thank you in advance!**